# Adding a column to a dataframe in pandas using another Column

Tags: pandas

So I have a column called "plot" in a dataframe and i want to create a new one called "keywords" which only has the important words of plot.
here is the code:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity 
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
 import re  
 import nltk
 nltk.download('stopwords')    
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
 df = pd.read_csv('IMDB_Top250Engmovies2_OMDB_Detailed.csv')
 df = df[['Title','Genre','Director','Actors','Plot']]
 df['Keywords'] = ''

 for index,row in df.iterrows():
     plot = row['Plot']
     plot = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]'," ", plot)
     plot = plot.lower()
     plot = plot.split()
     plot = [i for i in plot if not i in set(stopwords.words('english'))]
     plot = ' '.join(plot)                                          
     row['Key_words'] = str(plot)
```

And here is the output :(

[image]

Link to the csv : https://query.data.world/s/uikepcpffyo2nhig52xxeevdialfl7

Thank you !

Comment: Please, please. Avoid to include code in images. It wouldn't be possible for anyone to help you if he/she cannot copy paste your code to run it locally. You can edit your question and format the post with the original code.

Comment: Also: It's recommended that you clearly state what doesn't work. I kinda pieced together that you'd like your column to contain things. Welcome btw.

Answer (score 1):

Iterrow passes a copy of the row, not the reference. This should fix your problem:

```
df.loc[index,'Keywords'] = str(plot)
```

However, I would recommend using **apply**, imho it is more elegant. And it is alot faster.

That would looks something like this

```
def string_to_keywords(string):
    plot = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]'," ", string)
    plot = plot.lower()
    plot = plot.split()
    return " ".join([i for i in plot if not i in set(stopwords.words('english'))])

df["Keywords"] = df["Plot"].apply(string_to_keywords)
```

Comment: BTW: Extracting everything but the stopwords is a nice starting point. Once you get this to work, you might want to look into tfidf or attention, if you want to get sophisticated about it.

Comment: Ummm how to use appy here ?

Comment: I added that to the answer Abhinav.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like this

create function here:

```
def important_words(plot):
    # your code here
    return plot
```

make use of `apply` function:

```
df["Keywords"] = df.Plot.apply(lambda x: important_words(x))
```